# initGame is not defined

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to make a thing inspired by the game little alchemy and I found this code on jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/ngjbqa1p/

but when ı run it I get this:

`"ReferenceError: initGame is not defined"`

I can't seem to figure it out what's wrong

Comment: The fiddle uses an external library called `brine.js` that defines this function. Does your game load the library?

Comment: You can see that in the left sidebar section "Resources".

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the brine.js library in the Resources tab on the left-hand sidebar. Copy and paste the [link](http://www.jar42.com/brine/engine/brine.js) in the comments in the top part and, after testing it, it works fine.